# How do I fix ps fail in adb

Tags: multithreading, process, adb

I want to get the threads for my app. So I used the command like this. But I get bad pid '-T'

```
adb shell ps -T -p 29874
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you're using Android Nougat that does not use `ps` command from `toybox`.

Anyway, to get the threads list for your app you can use the following command:

```
adb shell ps 29874 -t
```

Source code of `ps` command:
https://github.com/xdtianyu/android-7.0.0_r1/blob/master/system/core/toolbox/ps.c